# a code namely OddEvenList(nList) that separates odd and even number into oddList[ ] and evenList[ ]

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

```
nList = [[2,5,99,99], [-3,8,1,2,10], [1, 7,100,10]] #pre-defined list
Output: oddList = [[2], [8, 2, 10], [100, 10]]
Output: evenList = [[5, 99, 99], [-3, 1], [1, 7]]
```

I can separate them as odd and even but I can't figure how to put them as nested list.

```
nList = [[2,5,99,99], [-3,8,1,2,10], [1, 7,100,10]]
evi_lis = []
odd_lis = []
for i in nList: #[2,5,99,99]
    for m in i:  #2
        if (m%2==0):
            evi_lis.append(m)
        else:
            odd_lis.append(m)
print(evi_lis)
print(odd_lis)
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
[2, 8, 2, 10, 100, 10]
[5, 99, 99, -3, 1, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty elegant solution is to use nested list comprehensions.

```
n_list = [[2,5,99,99], [-3,8,1,2,10], [1, 7,100,10]] #pre-defined list

odd_list = [[num for num in l if num%2 == 1] for l in n_list]
even_list = [[num for num in l if num%2 == 0] for l in n_list]

print(odd_list)
print(even_list)
```

Comment: Your comments are incorrect.  It DOES answer the posed question.  This produces two lists of lists, which is what was requested.  There is no way to do this action without nested loops, because you have to keep the nested lists intact.  The original code, with two loops, did not solve the problem because of that.  An efficient solution is useless if it is wrong.